# How to determine if {{user_picture}} is not empty in the comment.html.twig template

Tags: 8, theming

Trying to determine if {{user_picture}} is not empty in the comment.html.twig template.

`{{user_picture}}` refers to the Compact display mode for a User Entity.

The below code doesn't work.

```
{% if user_picture is not empty %}
      {{ user_picture }}  
    {% else %} 
      <img src="images/default_image" width="42" height="42">
    {% endif %}
```

Also tried this with no success...

```
{% if user_picture|render is not empty %}
```

Researched a bunch, and couldn't find any problems/solutions with this use case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment entity is available and you can get the author and its field data from that, e.g.

```
{% if comment.uid.entity.user_picture.target_id > 0 %}
  {{ user_picture }}
{% else %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```